# Maven re-build and deploy

Tags: maven, vim

I'm new to compiled web development, and I'm just trying to figure out the build/deploy process....  I've done:

```
mvn clean install
```

on a project, which built and deployed the project and now I can see it.  If I want to make changes to the codebase, do I really need to run mvn clean install again to re-build and deploy the changes or is there a way to do a quicker build without using a "proper" IDE?

I'm using vim/gvim

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maven already handles the dependencies and only re-builds the necessary files... unless you throw away all previous build artifacts with `clean`! You should only need to use `clean` when you run into problems, or when you have checked out a different version from version control. Usually, `mvn install` should suffice.

You can integrate that with Vim; the simplest is to

```
:set makeprg=mvn
```

and then trigger a build with `:make install`.

Plugins build on that simplistic setup, e.g. check out:

- [maven-plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4051)
- [maven-ide](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4096)

Comment: Thank you, Ingo!  Your answers are always so helpful and insightful.  Thank you for being so willing to act as a force for good and help others out! :)

Comment: Hey - in setting up the maven-ide, I'm getting "yavdb not patched?"  Any idea what that means?